# MySQL cross table regular expression match

Tags: mysql, regex, join

I have a web application and I am working on engine that analyzes referals.

Now I have table with pageviews along with referes that looks something like this:

```
pv_id        referer
------------------------------------------------------------
5531854534   http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8...
8161876343   http://google.cn/search?search=human+rights
8468434831   http://search.yahoo.com/search;_...
```

The second table contains sources definitions like:

```
source       regex
------------------------------------------------------------
Google       ^https?:\/\/[^\/]*google\.([a-z]{2,4})(\/.*)?$
Yahoo        ^https?:\/\/[^\/]*yahoo\.com(\/.*)?$
```

What I want is third table created by joinin these two:

```
pv_id        source
------------------------------------------------------------
5531854534   Google
8161876343   Google
8468434831   Yahoo
```

How to join these tables with regular expression?

UPDATE:

Changed last part of regex from `(\/.*|)` to `(\/.*)?`.

Comment: What are the pipelines doing at the end of your regexps? Third character from the right?

Comment: The last parentheses either selects `/something` (the `\/.*` part) or it has to be empty (nothing after pipeline :) These regexes work in Regular Expression Editor. But I will try that without the pipeline.

Comment: I changed the parenteses to `(\/.*)?` and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.pv_id, t2.source
from table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2 on (t1.referer regexp t2.regex)
```

Comment: This does not work. `SELECT 'http://www.google.com/' REGEXP '^https?:\/\/[^\/]*google\.com(\/.*|)$'` gives me `#1139 - Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp`. Something is wrong with my regexes maybe?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL:

```
SELECT a.pv_id, b.source 
FROM a, b
WHERE a.referer REGEXP b.regex
```